# How do I read this matrix and find the determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Here is the matrix, which I'm asked to give the determinant of.
How do I read this?

$$R^{(1)}:= \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
& \ddots \\
& & 0 & \cdots & 1 & &\\
& & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
& & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
& & & & & \ddots \\
& & & & & & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

How do I deal with the dots and find the determinant?

Comment: @FraGrechi I'm not given the dimensions, but the problem does mention row operations on a quadratic matrix; however, I'm not sure how that fits with this question.

Comment: I have never heard of the term "quadratic matrix", what does this refer to in the course/book you are currently taking/reading? Does this mean that you are dealing with an $n \times n$ square matrix?

Comment: @FraGrechi Yeah, it means square matrix.

Comment: Oh I am an idiot, of course it is a square matrix. To find the determinant simply swap those two rows, obtain $I$, and find that $\det R = -1$.

Comment: @FraGrechi Oh, thanks. That's what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As FraGrechi said, we can transform this matrix into the identity matrix, whose determinant is $1$; however, since we swap two rows, we need to multiply this by $-1$, giving us our final determinate of $-1$.